# how to declare database as variable in sql statment

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

i have problem declaring sql statement (MS SQL) database as variable i have this procedure ,
anyone can help thanks :)

```sql
DECLARE @ID int = 700001158
DECLARE @STRING VARCHAR(250) = 'StringResource_EN'

SELECT string.[value],item.[id] FROM ItemResource item LEFT JOIN **@STRING** string ON item.[name_id] = string.[code]
WHERE item.[id] = @ID
```

i got Error:

> [42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Must declare the table variable "@STRING". (1087)
>   Blockquote

while it should be this result :

> id = 700001158
>   value = Devildom Purge: Shield

Edited : 
i'v tried

```
DECLARE @ID int = 700001158
DECLARE @STRING VARCHAR(250) = 'StringResource_EN'
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(1000)

SET @sql =  'SELECT string.[value],item.[id] FROM ItemResource item LEFT JOIN '+@STRING+' string ON item.[name_id] = string.[code]
WHERE item.[id] = @ID'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

ALSO I got this

> [42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Must declare the scalar variable "@ID". (137)

Comment: Always include the error message also. They are important. And please explain what do you mean by “database as variable”

Comment: okey thank you i'll add

Comment: Also, if `@IN_STRING_DB` is meant to be a dynamic object, there's no reason to declare it as an `nvarchar(255)`. The longest length an object's name can have is 128 characters, so use `nvarchar(128)` or `sysname`.

Comment: If you want to declare a database as variable, you have two options: 1) use dynamic sql bystoring the sql command in a variable, or 2) use sqlcmd mode in which you can decalre your database name as variable https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/sqlcmd-use-with-scripting-variables?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: To answer your question, in your second block you embedded the string @id in your statement, not the **value** contained in that variable. Your logic is also incorrect (or your description misleading). The value contained in [at]string must be an object name - you said database name but that isn't correct. Given the terminology issues, you should rethink the decisions that lead to this path. This is beyond your skill level and will be difficult for you to implement and maintain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to need to use dynamic SQL for this one:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[cpanel_get_warehouse_item]
@IN_ACCOUNT_ID      INT,
@IN_STRING_DB VARCHAR(255),
@ITEM_COUNT         INT OUTPUT,
@GOLD           INT OUTPUT

AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
SET @ITEM_COUNT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Telecaster].dbo.[Item] WHERE [account_id] = @IN_ACCOUNT_ID AND [code] > 0)
SET @GOLD = (SELECT [cnt] FROM [Telecaster].dbo.[Item] WHERE [account_id] = @IN_ACCOUNT_ID AND [code] = 0 AND [gcode] = 126)

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(1000);

SELECT @sql =  'SELECT string.[value] as name,item.[code] as id ,item.[cnt],item.[level],item.[enhance],data.[icon_file_name] as icon
FROM [Telecaster].dbo.[Item] item LEFT JOIN [Arcadia].dbo.[ItemResource] data on data.[id] = item.[code]
LEFT JOIN [Arcadia].dbo.' + @IN_STRING_DB +  'string on data.[name_id] = string.[code]
WHERE item.[account_id] = ' + @IN_ACCOUNT_ID' + AND item.[code] > 0 ORDER BY item.[sid] asc'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

And as Milney rightly points out, whenever you use dynamic SQL you should be aware of SQL injection.

Comment: Bearing in mind that if the variable is user controlled in any way this opens you up to SQL Injection attacks: https://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/sql-injection/ so you are usually better finding an application level solution to this problem instead

Comment: I did

and I got 
[42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Must declare the scalar variable "@ID". (137)

Comment: @Jim Jimson
check the post please !! i'v did what you suggested

Comment: `QUOTENAME` is your friend. This is an injection issue right now.

Comment: I've updated. However I can't find anywhere you'd be seeing that error. Can you check your parameters please.

Comment: `sp_executesql` gives no protection here. `EXEC (@sql);` and `EXEC sp_executesql @sql;` is just as vulnerable here.